# How do not remove leading zero from variable in a Bash MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am trying to query against the database to validate if a registry exists. I created I bash script to make that:

```
read -p "`echo $'\n '`-------------`echo $'\n '` Insert a CPF: `echo $'\n '`-------------`echo $'\n '`" CPF
USER_IN_OPTOUT=$(mysql -u $BMB_MYSQL_USER -h $BMB_MYSQL_HOST -NB -se "SELECT cpf FROM optout WHERE cpf = $CPF;")
if [[ ${USER_IN_OPTOUT} == *"${CPF:0}"* ]]; then
    echo "----------------------------------------"
    echo "User already exists."
    echo "----------------------------------------"
else
    echo "---------------------------------------"
    echo "User does not exists."
    echo "---------------------------------------"
    exit 1
fi
```

The variable CPF (`$CPF`) is equal to `00324323721`. As this registry exists it returns the cpf, as expected. However, this query is removing leading zeros returning `324323721`. I expect that the returns be exactly `00324323721`. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you use `printf`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `cpf` in mysql? If it isn't numeric, then the `$CPF` in the WHERE clause should be surrounded in single quotes so it will be recognized as a string literal. If it is numeric, then you'll need to cast at is `varchar()` and pad it using something like `LPAD()`

Comment: @JNevill The data type is `varchar(11)`. It is casting to integer I think so.

Comment: @stephanmg I would like to use it after in a new query.

Comment: @JNevill surround in single quotes did not work! :/

Comment: Just to note, your prompt can be specified much more simply. `read -p $'\n-------------\nInsert a CPF:\n-------------\n ' CPF`

Comment: @JNevill select using `LPAD` works. However, I discovered that MySQL are saving the strings removing leading zero. It is strange! Do you know why?

Comment: It means the application or ETL that is loading this data into that table is not-great. `LPAD()` is a reasonable solution here, but if you are going to be running this alot, then you are going to be hitting your CPU a lot and it may be worth investigating why this data is being written without the leading zeros and fixing that.

Comment: @JNevill makes sense. Thank you for your worry. But it isn't a big application. It is simple enough to use `LPAD()` without any kind of headache.

Comment: @JNevill : Good comments as always, but I would argue the opposite and encourage removal of leading `00`s in an entry. Doesn't that imply that `000324323721`, `0000324323721` are different values as well? Seems crazy to me, but ... who knows, only the end users can say "I really need that!" ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: I'm with you @shellter. It totally depends on the definition of this data. I can say for sure in the instances where I have numeric strings with leading zeroes those leading zeroes are as important to the string as every other digit. But... yeah. It totally depends. Personally I only like storing actual numbers upon which arithmetic would be sensible as numeric, and everything else is string. But I know from experience that that is a big topic of debate amongst us database folk.

Comment: `show create table optout` can help